# Visitors to site get a file download instead of web page?

Tags: web-services, web-applications

Why do visitors to my site sometimes get a download to a file instead of the page to which they were supposed to go?

What problem does that point to - browser, controller, or something?

Comment: If you have a URL which people are having the problem with, that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually means your web server is serving the page up as the wrong MIME type.  You need to tell it which files should be served using which MIME types.  Apache includes a standard file for this, but I'm not sure which web server or platform you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Could possibly be that your HTTP server isn't providing the correct MIME type?

Comment: Nice, four seconds faster than me.  :P

Answer (score 0):

Either you have an invalid mime type configured when serving the page, so the browser thinks the content type is something it has to download because it can't display it, or if the problem happens only to some users, then the mime type you are choosing is something that those specific users don't have their browsers configured to support.